# What is virtual bridge with -nic in the end of name

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, bridge

When I use KVM, I create a virtual bridge called **virbr0**, there is also a bridge called **virbr0-nic**. Even after I disable and delete **virbr0**, the **virbr0-nic** is still there.

Can anyone explain to me what is this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The interface virbr0-nic is not a bridge, but a normal ethernet interface (although a virtual one, created with ip add type [veth](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html)).

It's there so that the bridge has at least one interface beneath it to steal it's mac address from. It passes no real traffic, since it's not really connected to any physical device.

The bridge would work without it, but then it could change it's mac address as interfaces enter and exit the bridge, and when the mac of the bridge changes, external switches may be confused, making the host lose network for some time.

Comment: A similar explanation (with slightly different phrasing) can be found here https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2012-September/msg00038.html

Comment: The exact type of `virbr0-nic` seems to be TAP device, according to `ip -details link show`

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev On my computer `virbr0-nic` is a TUN device. The command `ip -details link show virbr0-nic | egrep -woi "tun|tap|bridge|bridge_slave|vlan_tunnel"` outputs : `tun
bridge_slave
vlan_tunnel`