# What's the function of `virbr0` and `virbr0-nic`?

Tags: networking, kvm, libvirt

In my CentOS 7.2, I installed the below packages:

```
yum install -y epel-release qemu-kvm libvirt virt-install bridge-utils
```

then when I show `ip a`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:9a:8f:50:4a:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 13.19.241.25/29 brd 13.19.241.31 scope global em1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 13.19.241.26/8 brd 13.255.255.255 scope global em1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ea9a:8fff:fe50:4adc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:9a:8f:50:4a:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 103.193.241.25/29 brd 103.193.241.31 scope global em2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ea9a:8fff:fe50:4add/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:f9:a9:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:f9:a9:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You see there add two network devices: `virbr0` and `virbr0-nic`. what's them, what's the function of them?

and which package installed the two devices added?

Comment: See also: [What is virtual bridge with -nic in the end of name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378264/what-is-virtual-bridge-with-nic-in-the-end-of-name)

Answer (score 9):

When you installed the `libvirt` service, there will create the `virbr0` automatically, it is a `virtual network switch`.

all the virtual machines will connect to the `virbr0`.

by default, `virbr0` use NAT mode, can provide Internet access by NAT mode.
by default, `virbr0` assigned address `192.168.122.1`, and it can provide DHCP service for other virtual interface who connected to it.

if you use `brctl show`, you can find a interface of `virbr0` named `virbr0-nic`:

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
...
virbr0      8000.5254003caaaa   yes     virbr0-nic
```

Comment: So what _is_ `virbr0-nic` ... of course I can see it with `brctl`, but your answer dodges the aspect of what the `virb0-nic` interface is (older versions of `libvirt` did _not_ create it!).

Comment: Regarding the function of virbr0-nc (just to supply a MAC for the bridge) see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444863/31228