# debian virt-install with import not working No 'bridge' attribute specified

Tags: virsh

new to Debian from Centos
I'm trying to import an image
Does anyone have any idea what I would be doing wrong?

Debian VERSION="10 (buster)"
packages installed:

`apt-get install --no-install-recommends qemu-system libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system`

ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:6e:96:44:a0:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.x.x.x/25 brd 148.59.149.127 scope global eno3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:59:ec:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:59:ec:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

virsh net-list

```
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

When I try doing an import from a working image

```
virt-install --network default --name jitsi --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntu19.04 --ram=2024 --vcpus=2 --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu19.img,device=disk,bus=virtio -w model=virtio --import
```

error:

> Starting install...
> ERROR    internal error: No  'bridge' attribute specified with 
> Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.

I've tried adding instead
--network bridge=virbr0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was because I did not have a bridge br0.  Even when libvirt on install creates the virtual virbr0 switch that serves guests for DHCP and its own nat as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523258/139335)

It would still halt because it would not find any bridge interface outside its virtual environment I guess.

guests can be configured in their xml for interface type bridge as virbr0 or br0, which br0 gives the guest access to the outside world.

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:56:00:84'/>
      <source bridge='virbr0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

or

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:56:00:84'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

After creating a bridge with one of the physical interfaces, I was able to import or create guests.